# oauth2-oidc-sdk ParseException: "The none algorithm is not accepted"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, openid-connect, spring-security-oauth2

obviously I am not well versed in OAuth2 OpenID mechanics - just know the very basics.

I have successfully used the spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client to build my OAuth2 client. The server that I am talking to has a .well-known endpoint that describes the service. They have recently changed this endpoint implementation to include miscellaneous information like supported algorithms in the returned result.

In case of some particular fields, like, say "id_token_signing_alg_values_supported" there is an additional "none" algorithm included.

When I point oauth2 configuration to seek description from the new .well-known endpoint with these "none" algorithm entries, I get ParseException from oauth2-oidc-sdk library code:

```
Caused by: com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.ParseException: The none algorithm is not accepted
    at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.as.AuthorizationServerMetadata.parse(AuthorizationServerMetadata.java:1560) ~[oauth2-oidc-sdk-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]
    at com.nimbusds.openid.connect.sdk.op.OIDCProviderMetadata.parse(OIDCProviderMetadata.java:1190) ~[oauth2-oidc-sdk-7.1.1.jar:7.1.1]
...
```

I understand that probably the client code is angry that the server accepts "none" algorithm for some entries. I guess that the server I am talking to shouldn't expose ways for clients to send unencrypted stuff to it... but - if this is the case - I am a mere client - can I not forget about this and ignore this permission that the server gives to me to use this "none" algorithm? Is there no way to override this behavior? I looked through oauth2-oidc-sdk code and cannot find any means to do so.

Thank you.

[edit:] Specifically, oauth2-oidc-client does not accept "none" algorithm value in the following well-known configuration entries:

- token_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported
- introspection_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported
- revocation_endpoint_auth_signing_alg_values_supported

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The none algorithm is a very bad idea, because with this algorithm, any one can create their own tokens or modify existing tokens and the receiver of a token can't trust it. Also there's has been many security vulnerabilities related to none.

Like this one:

- [Critical vulnerabilities in JSON Web Token libraries](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/)

Comment: thanks - I will wait a bit hoping that maybe someone comes up with a solution to override this blank refusal from the client library part to parse this configuration - otherwise will mark this as the answer

Comment: No problems!  Can you not disable the none algorithm on the server?

Comment: it's a third-party server :)

Comment: just a crazy thought ,but could you not just copy the discovery document from the third party server and host your own version of it. And remove the alg none from it? Sure, if it changes on the srever, you won't notice, but it is a quick hack to get moving.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. yes, I tried that, sort of - but there is some glitch - some values, it seems, from the configuration, are calculated based on the base url that I specify as the location of the discovery document - well, exactly, I specify the base url of the issuer of the provided resources (spring.security.oauth2.client.provider.some_xx_provider.issuer-uri) - and the configuration is autodiscovered on {base-url}/.well-known/openid-configuration - this base-url seems to be later used - so if it's dummy then oauth2 workflow breaks - and I haven't found a way to mitigate that

Comment: of course I could use other methods - the self-hosting as you suggested, then just dumping the .well-known configuration - or introducing some kind of filter when reading that configuration to ignore the "none" entry - but I just wondered there would be some other sane way.. anyway, - thanks!!!

Comment: indeed we ended up asking the service provider to change the .well-known configuration and they agreed to do that citing that this used to be against the RFC anyway